# Ajax return Object object in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am new in codeigniter, but i have some problem:
I have form registration, which get inputs from  my form and add it to database, and show this data under the form registration.
My problem is in my ajax function,because it return my error and [object Object], or maybe its not problem in ajax.... I dont know...
Thanks for any help...
My view and script is:

```
<head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/main.css'); ?>" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.validate.js'); ?>"></script>
        <script>
        function AjaxFormRequest(result_id,form_id,url) { 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url:     url, //Адрес подгружаемой страницы 
                    type:     "POST", //Тип запроса 
                    dataType: "html", //Тип данных 
                    data: jQuery("#"+form_id).serialize(),  
                    success: function(response) { //Если все нормально 
                    document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response;
                    alert(response);
                }, 
                error: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);


                document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "Error on sending form"+response; 
                } 
             }); 
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="header"> 
            <h1>Welcome friend</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="center"> 
            <div id="move">
                <p>Please make your next move</p>
                <button type="button" onclick="show_button('in');">Sign in</button>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;or&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="button" onclick="show_button('up');">Sign up</button>
            </div>
            <div id="sigin">
                <!-- <form id="form" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="ajax()"> -->
                <form method="post" action="" id="myform">
                    <input maxlength="20" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
                    <br>    
                    <input maxlength="20" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                    <br>
                    <input maxlength="20" id="conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
                    <br>
                    <button id ="btsignin" type="submit" name="send" class="send" onclick="AjaxFormRequest('result', 'myform', '<? site_url().'/main/send' ?>')">Sign in</button>
                    <button id ="btsignup" type="submit" name="send" class="send" onclick="AjaxFormRequest('result', 'myform', '<? site_url('main/send'); ?>')">Sign up</button>
                </form>
                <!--  </form> -->
                <button id="cancel" onclick="cancel();">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            <div id="result" >
                <? var_dump(site_url().'/main/send');?>


            </div>
        </div>

    </center>

</body>
```

Main php is :

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    public function send() {

        if (!isset($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $error1 = "Email?<br />";
        }
        else
            $error1 = NULL;

        if (!isset($_POST['password']) or empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $error2 = "Password?<br />";
        }
        else
            $error3 = NULL;

        if (!isset($_POST['conf_password']) or empty($_POST['conf_password'])) {
            $error3 = "Confirm Password?<br />";
        }
        else
            $error4 = NULL;

        if (empty($error1) and empty($error2) and empty($error3)) {
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $type = 1;
            $this->load->library('userlib');
            if ($this->userlib->register($email, $password, $type, true)) {
            echo $_POST['email'];
            echo $_POST['password'];
               echo $_POST['conf_password'];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            echo $error1 . $error2 . $error3;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can You share Your AJAX-response here?

Comment: wen i do alert(response) it return me [obect Object]

Comment: open console (F12 at Chrome) -> Network tab -> find your request, open it and see at Response tab

Comment: This request heve no response data available

Comment: So You have error not at Your ajax-functions, but in Send(). Anyway, try to use Form Validation class (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Comment: also Your ajax-function sends serialized data from form with id `myform`. There're no forms with `id="myform"` in Your code.

Comment: this is form :<form method="post" action="" id="myform">

Comment: and how can help me validation library,i cant get any data in php file because its not calling from ajax